# The equation $9^x-2^{x+1/2}=2^{x+7/2}-3^{2x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation I'm trying to solve is
$$9^x-2^{x+1/2}=2^{x+7/2}-3^{2x-1}$$

---

*My attempt*

I first rewrote the equation like this
$$\begin{align}(3^x)^2-2^x \cdot 2^{1/2}&=2^x \cdot 2^{7/2}-(3^x)^2 \cdot 3^{-1} \\ \text{if }\,(3^x)^2-2^x \cdot \sqrt{2}&=2^x \cdot \sqrt{2^7}-(3^x)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\\ &=2^x \cdot \sqrt{128}-\frac{(3^x)^2}{3} \\ &=8 \cdot 2^x \cdot \sqrt{2}-\frac{(3^x)^2}{3}.\end{align}$$
If I let $a=2^x$ and $b=3^x$ I get
$$b^2-a\sqrt{2}=8a\sqrt{2}-\frac{b^2}{3}$$
And then I deduce
$$\begin{align} 0&=b^2+\frac{b^2}{3}-a\sqrt{2}-8a\sqrt{2} \\ &=\frac{3b^2+b^2}{3}-9a\sqrt{2} \\ &=\frac{4}{3}b^2-9a\sqrt{2} \\ &=4b^2-27a\sqrt{2}.\end{align}$$
But I can't continue from this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By grouping terms of like bases:

\begin{align}
  9^x-2^{x+\frac{1}{2}} &= 2^{x+\frac{7}{2}}-3^{2x-1} \\
  9^x+3^{2x-1} &= 2^{x+\frac{7}{2}}+2^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \\
  3^{2x-1} (3+1) &=
  2^{x+\frac{1}{2}} (2^3+1) \\
  3^{2x-1} 2^2 &=
  2^{x+\frac{1}{2}} 3^2 \\
  3^{2x-3} &= 2^{x-\frac{3}{2}} \\
  9^{2x-3} &= 2^{2x-3} \\
  (2x-3)(\log 9-\log 2) &= 0 \\
  2x-3 &= 0 \\
  x &= \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can write :
$log(4b^2) = log(27 a \sqrt(2))$
Using the log properties should give you easy access to $x$.